# Two iCloud accounts merged

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, messages

Recently, I have noticed that my partner's and my iPhones seem to be somehow linked or our iCloud accounts merged.

First, I noticed that she had all of my contacts on her phone. Today, I've realised that all my boarding passes and loyalty cards from the Apple Wallet have been transferred to her iPhone.

As a first measure, I thought this must be some sort of glitch and reset both iPhones (plus an iPad) to factory settings. Nothing has changed, in fact, I now have her Apple Wallet content (without credit cards) on my iPhone.

The devices:

- Two iPhone 6 running iOS 9.3.4
- One iPad Mini 2 running iOS 9.3.4
- Two MacBook Air's running OS X 10.11.5

We have an iCloud family account shared between our two accounts and a third member. The third member experiences no problems and does not receive any content. My partner is the Organised and I am listed as Parent/Guardian.

We use two separate MacBooks to sync our iPhones.

Possibly unrelated - although I am starting to doubt it - is another issue, whereby my partner does not receive text messages generated from online servers or non-iOS devices. When trying to activate iMessage and Facetime, **my** number is listed on **her** device. iMessage does not get activated, although it is on mine.

Have you guys got any ideas on how to resolve this mess?

Comment: First step would be to sign out of everything, iCloud, messages, FaceTime etc on all devices, then sign back in checking correct credentials are used. Then check that each device is set to its correct iCloud/email/phone number as primary contact & that none are shared. It kind of sounds like someone synced to the wrong Mac/iTunes [but that's pure guesswork]

Comment: @Tetsujin Okay, so signing out of all devices makes sense, but surely that would have already been done when restoring the devices to factory settings? All devices have the correct number, primary contact etc. As mentioned in the post, the devices have never been cross-synced, at least not with the Macs/iTunes.

Comment: @Tetsujin signing out of all devices did not change anything.

Comment: From your description it appears as if you both have different Apple IDs, but just to double check, is that the case? You don't share Apple IDs, iCloud accounts, or iTunes accounts, right?

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz that is correct. We don't share anything but we are part of an iCloud Family.